# How to port forward Internet protocol GRE(47) On My TP-Link Archer Xr500v

Tags: router, vpn, port-forwarding

How to port forward Internet protocol GRE(47) On My TP-Link Archer Xr500v Because I cant connect to my VPN server I Made. My router doesn't seem to have an option to forward GRE

Comment: GRE for VPN? You're not still using PPTP, are you? It's been broken and deprecated for over a decade now I think. If you're still using PPTP, please upgrade to a real VPN protocol.

Comment: Yes. im using PPTP